# How to exclude module but include class of that module in RDoc

Tags: class, module, jrubyonrails, rdoc

Running RDoc doesn't make sense for some modules that are blank. For example:

```
 class moduleName::className < ActiveRecord::Base

 def foo
 end

 def bar
 end

 end
```

RDoc produces report:

```
moduleName -> blank HTML
moduleName::className -> complete documentation
```

How to get remove moduleName, which is blank from report generation?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.